# Kill process by name using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I've got many java processes running with different jar files. I want to kill on explicit jar file process.

the following command doesn't work successfully:

`sudo kill $(ps -ef | grep example.jar | awk '{print $2}')`

It finds the correct PID, but can't kill it.

Comment: what is the output of `ps -ef | grep example.jar | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: there are come two PID's.
e.g.:
24523
25325

Comment: Try `sudo kill -9 PID` instead.

Comment: Add `| grep -v grep` before `awk` to exclude grepping.

Comment: `ps -eaf |grep example.jar |awk '!/grep/{print $2}'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

`ps -ef | grep PROCESS | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

kills all pids matching the search term of "PROCESS".

Comment: Try to avoid `kill -9` at least in the first run: [why?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8918/187424)

Comment: @DawidGrabowski   Thanks for the input, so does it mean we should run `kill -15` for the first time?

Comment: Yes, to allow process to exit cleanly.

Comment: thanks a lot for that one-liner - I ran a script, which is calling itself over and over again, hence there were plenty of the such processes all with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `killall` which allows you to kill processes by name:

```
killall -ir example.jar
```

the options:

- `-i` : interactive (asks confirmation for each process whether or not to kill it)
- `-r` : allows you to specify a regex. `killall` will try to kill all matching.

Answer (score 0):

`Awk` can perform what `grep` was doing here. This will search for pid of example.jar and then suppress the pid of awk itself.

```
kill $(ps -eaf |awk '/example.jar/ && !/awk/{print $2}')
```